# HTML: Which element/attribute to store id of entity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an index route which renders all persisted image entities from the database into some format like this:

```
<div class="image field">
  <h3>image-name</h3>
  <img src="imagefilename.jpg" />
</div>
```

How could I now render an id in each rendered div-image-container which jquery can parse and use for ajax?

Sry for forgetting:

I don't mean an id in form of an integer but as an string (slug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to HTML5 it seems the most appropriate way is to use data attributes for id and other user-defined attributes:

```
<div class="image field" data-id="1">
  <h3>image-name</h3>
  <img src="imagefilename.jpg" />
</div>
```

You can use id instead of data-id. But I think the **id** attribute is for DOM manipulating, while data-id is logic-based attrubute.

Comment: is also a slug string valid and no integer? Apart from that this seems to be the right way

Comment: I would be wary of cross browser support with the HTML5 data-* attributes

Comment: Ther are no problems with cross-browser support of this attributes. The one thing may be occured: if you use the html4 doctype, the W3C validator may throws warnings.

Comment: However which attribute should or can I now use? data-id? or is there some data-slug

Comment: You can use id or data-*** or both. Use what you want: "data-id" or "data-my_attribute_name", it makes no difference. I'm not fully understand what you means as "slug". The syntax is "data-[any_attribute_name]"

Comment: Ok thank you! A slug is a normalized (no spaces, or spec chars) entity-name which is url friendly. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to either add an `id` to the `<img>` tag, or you could use JQuery selectors to pick out every element with the same `<div>` structure like this

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ySL7/)

```
<div class="image-field">
    <h3>image-name</h3>
    <img src="image.png" />
</div>

$(function() {
   alert($('div.image-field img').attr('src'))
})

// will output: "image.png"
```

Note: I've altered the `id` on your containing `div` for this example

If you have multiple of these on a page you can loop over them as shown in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DtAhv/1/)

Comment: Hi brad, I would like to store the slug as id somewhere in the container in an attribute

Comment: note that, even if not needed for the task (as demonstrated), you can still use $('div.image-field').attr('data-id') if you wish to have that id and using @odiszapc sugestion

Comment: for getting the attribute jquery's .prop is better :)